# XPages conflit is created...inline edit repeat control

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have my Notes View where there are a panel bind to NotesDocument...for every row.
All work correctly..I can edit/save every row. Work very well.

But I have a xp:BUTTON in top of my xpages (outside repeat control).
When the user press the button, the event handler execute a SSJS code that update a field
for all entries of my view with the method **stampAll**

In this case...if I edit every row of my repeat control...this generate a conflit problem...

I think that the problem is the allocate memory?

Have you some suggest?

Comment: Have you defined a 'scope' for your Notes View datasource?

Comment: Does your button do a partial refresh of the repeat control?  If not, I would think it could generate conflicts if they are also edited within the repeat.

Comment: I'd be interested to see some code of the this....

Comment: I agree with @Steve.  If you are touching all the documents of a particular view in the background while they are also loaded in the front-end, then alter those documents in the front-end without refreshing or reloading the page, then you will get conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Edit and save a relatively new document using inline. Check the last updated date by looking at the view in Notes Client. Then use the button and check last updated dates of the main and conflict document. This will tell you if the problem is updating a cached set of documents or a double-save.

Two thoughts:

1. If the button is a Submit type, it may save all datasources on the page. That will cause conflicts, but it would do so on all documents in the repeat control.
2. How is the inline edit save performed? Perhaps that save is being triggered at the same time the button stampAll happens.
3. Are you reloading the page after the button is used? If you're then using inline edit, and that causes the conflict, Greg will be correct that you're editing a document via back end and front end.